# bash command to change tabs in terminal by index

Tags: bash, terminal

What is a bash command to change to a different terminal tab by tab name or by index in mac?

I'm writing a bash script where I open different tabs, but I don't know how to get back to the previous tabs

Comment: May not even exist; this is a question of scripting capabilities / remote API supported by the specific terminal program you're using. An answer for iTerm is likely to be different from an answer from Apple's built-in Terminal, etc.

Comment: (As such, this needs to be more a question about that terminal program than it is a question about bash; if you *had* a command for the purpose, you could use it from any language, not just bash -- f/e, from Python with the `subprocess` module; with an `execve()` call from C, etc).

Comment: @Charles Duffy ya, I thought that this may be an issue, but I did install for example ttab which allowed to create additional tabs, so there should be some way to change them if I can create them.

Comment: Is ttab open-source? Find the source, identify the API it's calling, look up the documentation for that API.

Comment: ...but my point was that bash doesn't have *any* built-in functionality for interacting with terminal GUIs, so anything/everything that's available to you is a function of the APIs available for your specific terminal (and/or generic OS-level automation tooling, again not specific to bash).

Comment: okay, thank you, but a quick search for either terminal or iTerm doesn't show me any command, I mean it's possible that it's not doable, best I could do is most likely checkout ttab as you mentioned, but it's strange that I can't find a quick answer online for something as simple as this or that no one else has encountered this issue

Comment: You're not finding much because bash isn't used to control applications like you're trying to do. It might be worth a few minutes looking for an Apple Script solution, which you could execute via bash.

Comment: ya, a quick google search gave me an answer. I'll try and implement it and then post  a solution to my own question, thank you :)